# Card residence EU family article 10

Tags: uk, international-travel, eu, study

Directive 2004/38/EC say if you have card resident EU family member you can travel in the UK accompany citizen EEA without visa for no more than 3 months.

My question is can a "non EU member" (card resident EU family) stay and study for more than 3 months without member EEA (only)?

Comment: I think the answer is ‘No’. Family members are covered by the right of free movement, but only as a dependent of the EEA citizen. The right is limited to the EEA state in which the EEA citizen is exercising treaty rights. Therefore, if the EEA citizen is not exercising their treaty rights in the UK, the family member has no derived rights in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

Third country nationals can only benefit from EU law when they join or accompany an EU citizen making use of their treaty rights in the UK. That's true for short-term visits (with or without EEA family permit) and for longer term stay. If they live with their EEA citizen sponsor, they are certainly allowed to study in the UK.

Otherwise, they are still allowed to work or study but under the common immigration rules (which might require some expensive visa or to meet rather onerous requirements depending on your exact situation).